# how to move the UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, touch

i create a UIButton *actionbtn,it's default image is 1.png,and hightlight image is 2.png, i select this button,and move it to any place of the screen.my code is

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchMoved = [touch locationInView:self];
    actionbtn.frame = CGRectMake(touchMoved.x-40, touchMoved.y-40, 80, 80);
}
```

if i clicked the button and move it,it can not be moved,but if i touch the screen,and move on the screen the button can work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007315

It's an example with an UIButton that move on screen...

Answer (score 0):

The button is moving when you keep touching the screen because you implemented `-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`. If you attempted to move the button when simply touching the screen anywhere, place that code in `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`.

Comment: i mean i can only move the BUTTON,not others

Answer (score 0):

add an if clause in touchesMoved function.

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];    
if( touch.view == button){
     [button.center = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    }
```